# Язык программированя Си: как инициализировать "кучу" после выделения памяти, как массив?

Tags: c

Как "красиво" можно инициализировать память после выполнения malloc(), как, например, инициализируется массив. Например:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
size_t* a = malloc(11 * sizeof(size_t));
//a[11] = {11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1}; 
a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
a[2]=3;
a[3]=4;
a[4]=5;
a[5]=6;
a[6]=7;
a[7]=8;
a[8]=9;
a[9]=10;
a[10]=11;
  
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  printf("%d: %ld\n", i, a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
free(a);
}
```

В реальной задаче вместо size_t используется float complex, но суть не меняется.

Comment: `size_t tmp[11] = {1, 2, 3}; memcpy(a, tmp, 11*sizeof*a);`

Comment: И зачем оно в куче, когда есть копия на стеке)

Comment: Такая инициализация в любом случае выполняется путем ряда присваиваний во время выполнения программы, так что вопрос "красоты" — никак не вопрос эффективности.

В вашем конкретном случае `for(int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)a[i]=i+1;`

Comment: А почему не сделать проще - https://ideone.com/d2M81W ? :)

Comment: @wololo для наибольшей эффективности нужно чтобы экземпляр массива `tmp` хранился в самом коде : `static size_t const tmp[11]={...};memcpy..`